# How to have multiple colors on a jlabel when the text is constantly changing?

Tags: html, netbeans

If this is the code to have multiple colors in html format in a jlabel

```
"<html><font color=red>Message</font> - <font color=navy>message</font></html>"
```

is there a way I can change the message? Im using this in  a java app and when I try to change the message to the variable name it just gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you read other topic about multiple color in a Label already.

So it is legel and work like

```
Lable.setText("<html>......</html>")
```

If you want it automatically change.

You have to add few different statements of Lable and make it run at background.